# Can I use inner product between two scalars?

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is can I use inner product between two scalars?
Do they satisfy the properties of inner product such as angle? 
It seems to me that scalar only has angle either 0 or 180?

Also, can I use scalars when calculating the kernel matrix (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method)? Is it meaningful to use scalar when calculating the kernel matrix?

Comment: The normal multiplication makes the real numbers an inner product space, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are in a real vector space of dimension one you have $V=\mathbb{R}$ and the inner product is just

$$\langle x,y\rangle_{\mathbb{R}}=xy.$$
and indeed you have $\theta=0$ or $\pi$ as you said.

However if you go into a complex vector space of dimension one you have $V=\mathbb{C}$ and you need:

$$\langle x,y\rangle_{\mathbb{C}}=\overline{x}y,$$

where $\overline{x}$ is the complex conjugate of $x$.

If you write your complex numbers in the form $z=|z|e^{i\theta}$ you will see that the angles between your scalars/vectors can be anything in $[0,2\pi]$.